# Drawable xhdpi image error in android

Tags: android

I used six folders in my android application which is drawable-ldpi,mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,and xxxhdpi.Ohter folder is ok except drawable-xhdpi.I created drawable ldpi is 90x72,mdpi is 120x96,hdpi is 180x144, xhdpi is 240x192, xxhdpi is 360x288 and xxxhdpi is 480x384.I am tested  in galaxy J7 after released apk which is ok by 240x192.But ,if I installed in my sony z ultra ,it is problem because image is small.My sony z ultra is ok if I set 360x288 in xhdpi folder.But,galaxy J7 and sony z ultra have same 1080x1920px.I don't know how can I do that ?Please help me kindly.Sorry for my stupid question.

Comment: I think you don't understand how DPI works in general.

Comment: their screen densities must be different.

Comment: I used 320 dpi in my sony z ultra.

Answer (score 0):

MDPI should be your baseline. ie, the base size.

Then image(drawable) sizes should be;

LDPI is 0.75*MPDI

HDPI is 1.5*MDPI

XHDPI is 2*MPDI

XXHDPI is 3*MDPI

XXXHDPI is 4*MDPI